# Python - Selenium Stale exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to automate Microsoft login page. However when I try to click the sIgn in button no error occurs but the button does not get clicked.

Language used - Python

Below is my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.chrome()
url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
driver.get(url)
button=driver.find.element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"])
username=driver.find.element_by_id("i0116")
username.clear()
username..sendkeys(zyz@gmail.com)
button.click()
password =driver.find.element_by_id("i0118")
password.clear()
password.sendkeys(zyzass)
try:
   button.click()
expect StaleElementReferenceException:
   print("loggedin")
```

Expected Result -
1.Login to https://login.microsoftonline.com/
2.enter username
3.Click on Next button
4.enter password
5.click on  Sign in

Actual Result -
1.Login to https://login.microsoftonline.com/
2.enter username
3.Click on Next button
4.enter password
5.**click does not work**

There is no error when code is run.

Comment: can you accept the answer as you commented it is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic example of Stale Element problem.
You got the `next` button by

```
button=driver.find.element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"])
```

At the beginning.
Then you inserted the email address and pressed the `next` button.
Now you are on another web page, the pointers / references to elements located on the previous page no more valid.
So when now you are trying to access the element defined on the previous page by

```
button.click()
```

it doesn't work.
Stale Element Exception is thrown.
To make it work you have to define / get the `next` button element again with

```
button=driver.find.element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"])
```

There is no error actually presented in your code run since you are catching the exception with

```
try:
   button.click()
expect StaleElementReferenceException:
```

block however you are still not inside the system as you print inside the

```
expect StaleElementReferenceException:
   print("loggedin")
```

Read more about Stale Element [here](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/) or at any other available tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have checked with these lines of code, and it works fine there are 
lots of syntactical error in your code, So I've tried with the correct ways, You can check with this

browser.maximize_window()

userId = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='email' and @name='loginfmt']")))
userId.send_keys("zyz@gmail.com")

next=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='idSIButton9']")))
next.click()

password = WebDriverWait(browser,10) .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='password' and @name='passwd']")))
password.send_keys("zyzass")

signIn=WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@value='Sign in']")))
signIn.click()
```

I've used `explicitWait`

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```